# Django having issues with django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I've been following an online tutorial on django registration. They are using `django-registration-redux==1.1`, and I have to use `django-registration-redux==1.4`. I start my local server and go to this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

I then see this error:
`TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/`

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'store']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/xx/Desktop/stoneriverelearning/bookstore/store/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)


Template error:
In template /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/templates/registration/registration_form.html, error at line 1
   base.html   1 :  {% extends "registration/ registration_base.html" %}
   2 : {% load i18n %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block title %}{% trans "Register for an account" %}{% endblock %}
   5 : 
   6 : {% block content %}
   7 : <form method="post" action="">
   8 :     {% csrf_token %}
   9 :     {{ form.as_p }}
   10 :     <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
   11 : </form>


Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  97.             reraise(exc, self.backend)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in reraise
  107.     six.reraise(exc.__class__, new, sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  151.         compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in get_parent
  148.         return self.find_template(parent, context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in find_template
  128.             template_name, skip=history,

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  169.         raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: base.html
```

I'm getting that the difference would be that I have to do something different in this newer version to get it to find all the new registration html files and txt files (for email), but how do I do this?

EDIT:

So thanks for pointing out the space here:

```
{% extends "registration/ registration_base.html" %}
```

How can this be removed? I don't have this in my code that I know of.

Here is my urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

]

Thanks :)

Comment: @crowson is talking about `{% extends "registration/ registration_base.html" %}`, you should have `{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}`

Comment: this looks like the issue, but I'm not sure where that is. I don't have a registration_base.html. So it must be when referencing it it put it in. Where is this?

Comment: Man, you should be looking at the error! It says `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/templates/registration/registration_form.html, error at line 1` So it's in your `django-registration-redux` package, but i don't know why you have source with a broken line. Try to reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a space in line 1 of your template when referencing the file name. If that's not it, you may have another folder locally named registration that django is looking in instead of the registration package.